# How does Spring boot Application runs under the hood?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am new to spring boot and for build tool i am using Maven .
I wanted to know that how does spring boot application runs after maven build process finishes like

**What is the output of the build ?**

**How build is executed ?**

Although much of the detail about the build and run process is abstracted away by IDE (like IntelliJ) but i am curious to know about what happens internally ?

Comment: During build there is nothing special going on, is is just maven. During runtime spring does a lot of reflection and class loading to create and inject beans.

Comment: No, i wanted to ask how is build executed. like output of build process is JAR/ WAR. What is next process after build and who invokes it?

Comment: So you are asking about the spring-boot-maven-plugin? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

The [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/) Maven Plugin can generate an executable JAR which includes all dependency JARs and start-up, classloader code in addition to you application code.